# Can't install Git in Godaddy web hosting

Tags: linux, ssh, git, web-hosting, godaddy

I am hosting a website in Godaddy web hosting. I want to install Git. I am using SSH to connect to my site. I find this link from Godaddy [How to install Git in Linux web hosting](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/how-to-install-git-on-linux-web-hosting-12391). I followed their instructions. When I reach:

```
wget https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.1.2.tar.gz
```

I get:

```
xxx@xxx [/home]$ wget https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.1.2.tar.gz
--2017-09-02 13:09:37--  https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.1.2.tar.gz
Resolving git-core.googlecode.com... 74.125.28.82, 2607:f8b0:400e:c04::52
Connecting to git-core.googlecode.com|74.125.28.82|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-09-02 13:09:37 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

It seems the file in the link does not exist any more. Can you please suggest to me how can I install Git in Godaddy web hosting? I am a Windows user with little familiarity in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It seems the file in the link does not exist any more.

You can retrieve the file from the [Google Code Archive](https://code.google.com/archive/).

See in particular [git-core](https://code.google.com/archive/p/git-core/downloads), which contains a link to [git-1.8.1.2.tar.gz](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/git-core/git-1.8.1.2.tar.gz).

You could, of course, consider using the latest version which is [git-1.9.0.tar.gz](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/git-core/git-1.9.0.tar.gz).

Comment: Thanks. But what is the link? when I try [this link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/git-core/downloads/git-1.9.0.tar.gz) in the `wget` command I get error page. Can you type the link that I should use with `wget`? or type the whole `wget` command?

Comment: @user6875880  Try `wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/git-core/git-1.8.1.2.tar.gz`

Comment: This is the result: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2017-09-02 13:54:01 ERROR 400: Bad Request.`

Comment: For the latest version `wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/git-core/git-1.9.0.tar.gz`

Comment: `Connecting to storage.googleapis.com|172.217.4.144|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4839724 (4.6M) [application/octet-stream]
git-1.9.0.tar.gz: Permission denied

Cannot write to git-1.9.0.tar.gz (Success).`

Comment: It did not download it. I tried: `tar -zxf git-1.9.0.tar.gz` then I got:
`tar (child): git-1.9.0.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory`
`tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now`
`tar: Child returned status 2`
`tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

Comment: Can you clarify how to check the permissions? the `sudo` command does not work in this distribution. I do not know which Linux godaddy webhosting is actually use.

Comment: @user6875880 You need to have write permission in the directory where you are downloading.

Comment: @user6875880 [Give user write access to folder](//askubuntu.com/q/402980)

Comment: @user6875880 If you don't have `sudo` I don't know. You will have to ask goddady.